# ReflectionException Error in Laravel 5.5 after deployment to live server

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

Due to unable to access Terminal in hosting server, I ran composer update in my local machine and uploaded everything including vendor folder, composer.json and composer.lock. My hosting server run PHP 7.1 and so does my local machine with Laravel 5.5.

**Now I am facing PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught ReflectionException: Class view does not exist in /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php:752**
Stack trace:

#0 /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(752): ReflectionClass->__construct('view')

#1 /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(631): Illuminate\Container\Container->build('view')

#2 /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php(586): Illuminate\Container\Container->resolve('view', Array)

#3 /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/Application.php(732): Illuminate\Container\Container->make('view', Array)

#4 /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/helpers.php(110): Illuminate\Foundation\Application->make('view', Array)

#5 /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Found in /public_html/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Container/Container.php on line 752

I ran the following command.

```
composer require maatwebsite/excel --no-update
composer update maatwebsite/excel
```

And I uploaded the following files and folder from local to live server.

1. Vendor / maatwebsite folder   and all other newly created by folders.
2. vendor / composer folder
3. composer.json
4. composer.lock

I cleared config cache, route cache, view cache from PHP file using artisan command.

Can anyone please help me to debug the error?
Thank you.

Comment: run the command `composer dump-autoload`

Comment: @DevsiOdedra, I have already uploaded updated autoload_classmap.php in vendor/composer folder. Do I need to create or generate new one from "composer dump-autoload" command for live environment?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing bootstrap/cache/packages.php and bootstrap/cache/services.php

These files are updated when you run composer require or update as part of the package discovery.

Comment: An easy way to see what files changed that you need to update on the server is by using Beyond Compare by Scooter Software. You can compare your local files to the server files through an SSH or FTP connection. It's saved my tail a number of times.

Comment: absolutely "bootstrap/cache/services.php" does the job. Thanks a lot.